# WPF - Can't assign Styles to a UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, styles

How can I set properties of a UserControl with styles? (I read the related questions, but none of them solved my problem)

I define a simple UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.RedSquare"
    ...
    Height="10" Width="10" Background="Red">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can now manually assign the Width/Height of this control.

But I can´t assign the properties with styles.

This does not work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="red" TargetType="{x:Type local:RedSquare}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

...

<local:RedSquare Style="{StaticResource red}" />
```

Strange behaviour: i can modify the control´s margin with a style but all other properties do not work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user control has hard-coded width and height:

```
Height="10" Width="10"
```

local property values have a higher precedence that values in a style setter. Try replacing your width / height with design-time values:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DesignHeight="10" d:DesignWidth="10"
```

Regards,
Colin E.

Comment: As an alternative, you could also just leave the hard-coded values out